# Use Query to display two columns and group rows based on one column's count?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm using an array to bring 2 columns of data together from 3 sheets.

There are duplicates in the second column, and I would like to group those duplicates together and display both `Col1` and `Col2`, ordered alphabetically by `Col1`.

This is the formula I have right now:
`=QUERY({'Sheet1!'A:B;'Sheet2!'A:B;'Sheet3!'A:B}, "Select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1",1)`
Which only displays `Col1`.

I've tried nesting `QUERY`, but I can't get it to work and can't find any direction anywhere online.

Here's an example sheet I made to show what I'm trying to do:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_x0mXZC0ZjsHDCd6I0dDf9OI19lrzEcPYqfcMxuK74Y/edit?usp=sharing

In the example if an employee is listed twice the name may change but the email is consistent. I'm hoping to group by the email addresses and return only one name (it doesn't really matter which name).

I'm not sure if this is possible without formulas in more than one cell. Thank you either way!

Comment: We don't know what your data looks like, the type of that data, etc. Do you really want COUNT in your QUERY, or would SUM be better? There's no way for us to know without access to what you're seeing. If you make a copy/sample sheet and share the link here, being sure to set permission to "Anyone with the link can edit," I or someone else here will be able to help you quickly and accurately.

Comment: Thank you - I've added a link to an example Google sheet and clarified the question. I'm trying to group email addresses together if they're the same, while only showing a single name especially if the names change while the email addresses stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@confuseddesk, try this array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({VLOOKUP(UNIQUE({Sheet2!B2:B;Sheet3!B2:B;Sheet4!B2:B}),{Sheet2!B2:B,Sheet2!A2:A;Sheet3!B2:B,Sheet3!A2:A;Sheet4!B2:B,Sheet4!A2:A},2,FALSE),UNIQUE({Sheet2!B2:B;Sheet3!B2:B;Sheet4!B2:B})},"Select * Where Col2 Is Not Null"))
```

Comment: Thank you!! This nailed it. I missed the alternating ```,``` and ```;``` in your ```VLOOKUP``` initially when I tried to copy the formula over, but once I straightened those out it worked perfectly.

Comment: Happy to hear it. Yes, in "curly-bracket arrays," a comma means "move right," and a semicolon means "move to next row."